# Bash Variable within string, within string

Tags: json, bash

So, I am trying to run a Python script from within a Bash script. The Python script takes one of its parameters in the form of a JSON string, which looks like this:

`'[{"CONFIG":"SomeConfigID"}]' //there are other members available but this is all I need.`

I would like to pass in a variable from the Bash script as a member of the JSON object. So, This is what I am doing:

`'[{"CONFIG":"${CONFIG}"}]'`

However, what I find is that the Python script fails because it does not recognise `${CONFIG}`

For some reason, Bash is not replacing that expression with the value of the variable. I am unfamiliar with Bash, so this may simply be something obvious that I am missing. Can anybody help? Is there some other way to construct this JSON string that would not cause this problem?

Comment: In Bash, a variable within single quotes is treated as literal. To have its value expanded you need to double quote it. Thus, you must probably swap the quotes you are using: does `"[{'CONFIG':'${CONFIG}'}]"` work to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the right quoting in place for shell expansion:

```
'[{"CONFIG":"'"${CONFIG}"'"}]'
```

As shell variable must not in single quote for shell to expand them.

**Example:**

```
CONFIG=foo
echo '[{"CONFIG":"'"${CONFIG}"'"}]'
[{"CONFIG":"foo"}]
```